# Send form data to API from nodejs

Tags: node.js, graphql

Earlier I was using rest API to upload my files to the server. I had input type file and I was sending the form data to the server with that API. It was working fine but now I have to use graphql mutation for the same. We have an apollo server running app where I have used the same API to upload our images but it seems that file object was not in the same format as it was expected by rest API. So my question is how can we create same file object like we have in browser from nodejs.

We are using `RESTDataSource` to make HTTP calls in graphql app

My schema

```
type Mutation {
   uploadFile(file: Upload!): Boolean!
}
```

Here is my resolver

```
import { createWriteStream, createReadStream } from 'fs';
import FormData from 'form-data';

async uploadFile(file: any): Promise<any> {
        const url = new URL(`https://dev.dummber.com/portal/file/v1/uploadFile`);
        const { createReadStream: apolloFileStream, mimetype, filename }  =  await file;
        const tempFilename = `${filename}`;
        const stream = apolloFileStream();
        const wstream = createWriteStream(tempFilename);
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            stream
                .pipe(wstream)
                .on('finish', () => resolve())
                .on('error', () => reject());
        });
        const rstream = createReadStream(tempFilename);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('uploadingFile', rstream);
        const response = await this.post(url.toString(),
            {
                data: formData
            }
        , {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        });

        return true
    }
```

Comment: its a just a keyname, backend team will look for this key in form data

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec